# Global not working as I thought

Tags: python

I'm not able to understand why the global variable is not working.

```
global globalvar
globalvar = 0
def print_globalvar():
        globalvar = globalvar + 1
        print globalvar

def print_var():
        print_globalvar()
        globalvar = 10
        print_globalvar()

print_var()
```

Traceback for the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print_var()
  File "test.py", line 9, in print_var
    print_globalvar()
  File "test.py", line 5, in print_globalvar
    globalvar = globalvar + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'globalvar' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You didn't tell Python it is a global in the right place; assignment to the variable tells Python it is a local instead. Add `global globalvar` *in the functions*.

Comment: Using `global` at the global level is.. pointless as Python knows that those variables are global already.

Comment: Thanks I didn't properly how to use these global variables properly

Comment: The proper way to use ``global`` is not to use it at all!